# I'm learning web development with flask and recently ran into a json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**This is my code:-**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json
import datetime

with open ("config.json", "r", errors="ignore") as c:
     parameters = json.load(c)["parameters"]
local_server = True

app = Flask(__name__)
if local_server:
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = parameters["local_uri"]
else:
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = parameters["prod_uri"]
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Contacts(db.Model):
    '''
     sno, name, email, message, date
    '''
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    message = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

@app.route("/")
def index ():
    return render_template('index.html', parameters=parameters)

@app.route("/about/")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', parameters=parameters) 

@app.route("/contact/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    if(request.method=='POST'):
      '''Add entry to the database'''
      name = request.form.get('name')
      email = request.form.get('email')
      message = request.form.get('message')
      entry = Contacts(name=name, message=message, date=datetime.date.today(), email=email )
      db.session.add(entry)
      db.session.commit()
      return render_template('contact.html', parameters=parameters)


app.run(debug=True)
```

**and this is my json file saved as config.json:-**

```
{
  "parameters":

   {

    "local_server": "True",
    "local_uri": "mysql://root:@localhost/coderoad",
    "prod_uri": "mysql://root:@localhost/coderoad",
    "git_url": "github.com/road2code"  
   }

}
```

**This is my error:-**

```
PS C:\Users\shomi\OneDrive\Desktop\Flask> & C:/Users/shomi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Users/shomi/OneDrive/Desktop/Flask/flask3.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/shomi/OneDrive/Desktop/Flask/flask3.py", line 7, in <module>
    parameters = json.load(c)["parameters"]
  File "C:\Users\shomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\shomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\shomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\shomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I'm working on a bootstrap template, even after banging my head around google I am unable to find a solution, a little help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to specify path to config.json, perhaps './config.json'; also, try loading it in repl (e.g. ipython)

I don't know where your config.json resides relative to your flask app. If relative path doesn't work, try using complete path.

```py
with open ("./config.json", "r", errors="ignore") as c:
     parameters = json.load(c)["parameters"]
```

update:

try this

```py
with open('foo.bar', 'w') as dummy:
  dummy.write('dummy')
```

put this before your the code that reads the config.json . Here, i'm not specifying the path to 'foo.bar', just like you didn't when you were trying to read config.json. After you run your app again, the location of foo.bar will be the location where flask is trying to read config.json from.

Comment: Where exactly I need to specify the './config.json' path???

Comment: Try running your code in a repl (ipython is a good one).  Just the part where you open and read the config file.

Comment: yeah so I tried running the code which is associated to reading the config file and it seems to run fine, then what in the world goes wrong when I put my parameters???

Comment: How do you run your flask app? Are you starting repl from the same directory? Another thing to try, is try to create a dummy file from flask - open a file and write someting into it, then find that file - this will tell you what your app considers it's current dir.

Comment: I use VS code and yes my config.json and flask app are in same directory, as I mentioned above that running the code which is associated to reading the json file does not gives me error, and I quite didn't understood that creating a dummy file part.

Comment: The error that you're seeing implies that python can't find the file you're trying to read. In order to figure out where it's trying to read from, i suggest to add code that would create a dummy file (we don't care about its contents, just the file itself). Put the code that creates the dummy file before the code that reads the config. Run your app again. Then find the dummy file on your disk. The location of the file will be the location where flask is trying to read your config file from.